# How do I stop BitTorrent Sync (Resilio) service?

Tags: sync, services, bittorrent

Gui in `http://localhost:8888/gui/` can only Pause synchronizing.

Answer (score 1):

From "[Running Sync in configuration mode – Sync](https://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/204762689-Running-Sync-in-configuration-mode)"

```
pkill btsync
```

Alternatively, from [Installing Sync on Linux](https://help.getsync.com/hc/en-us/articles/207689576-Installing-Sync-on-Linux)

```
sudo service btsync stop
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Ubuntu 14.10 and Earlier

If your OS uses sysvinit, upstart, control Sync with the following commands:

```
sudo service btsync (command)
```

**where (command) can be `start`, `stop`, or `restart`**

#### Ubuntu 15.04 and Later

If your OS uses systemd, use the following commands to control Sync:

```
sudo systemctl (command) btsync
```

where (command) can be `start`, `stop`, `enable`, `disable`, or `status`

### Permissions and users

Note, that when you install Sync package it is going to add `btsync` user to your Linux and run under `btsync` user. Take care of permissions and groups before you start syncing.

If you are using Ubuntu 15.04 or later it is possible to run Sync under your current user account, if you start it with the command:

```
sudo systemctl --user (command) btsync
```

Unfortunately, this option is not available for 14.10 or earlier.